# $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{a}{x-a}\operatorname{Si}_a(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, trigonometric-integrals

> Let $a>0$ and $\operatorname{Si}_a(x)=\int_{a}^{x}\frac{\sin(t)}{t} \, dt$. Compute
> \begin{equation*}
> \lim_{x\to a}\frac{a}{x-a}\operatorname{Si}_a(x)
> \end{equation*}
> My reasoning was: suppose $F$ is such that $F'(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. Then
> $$a\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\operatorname{Si}_a(x)}{x-a}=a \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x)-F(a)}{x-a} = a F'(a) = a \frac{\sin(a)}{a} = \sin(a)$$

<s>I know this is incorrect</s>, but it gives the correct solution. Does anyone know how to properly solve this?

**Edit**: Since $f(t)=\frac{sin(t)}{t}$ is continuous in $(0,\infty)$ (in particular is continuous in $(a,x)$), we can use the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) and write Si$_a(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t) \ dt = F(x)-F(a)$.

Comment: What seems to be the problem with just taking $F = \operatorname{Si}_a$? Since $\sin(x)/x$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$, $\operatorname{Si}_a$ is differentiable there.

Comment: *"I know this is incorrect"* - wait, why do you think your work is incorrect?

Comment: Is my assumption correct? It is because the function is continuous in that interval? I just thought that wasn't rigorous.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my post.

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus says that this limit equals $a\cdot\dfrac{\sin a} {a} =\sin a$. We don't need to invoke any function like $F$ or anti-derivatives.